# Why isn't browser dependent CSS used?

Tags: javascript, css

For example, SO throws over 50 CSS errors and warnings on loading as do most popular sites.

Simply detecting the correct browser and loading the correct CSS dynamically would be simple.

I'm trying to understand why these errors/warnings are ignored by most sites?

Even though the performance hit of parsing the useless CSS is likely in the micro-second range, isn't it just sloppy coding?

Comment: Because they're not critical errors, *and* because the performance hit of parsing the useless CSS is so small; the performance hit of browser detection is much greater.

Comment: And how do you detect the correct browser?

Comment: I think that the main reason is just for ease of development.  Setting up CSS rules for individual browsers *and* implementing correct browser detection takes more time than ... not doing that, and there is no benefit except maybe some devs won't be able to see any CSS errors

Comment: Keeping different CSS files for every possible browser would be a nightmare.  Writing CSS correctly to the specifications is not "sloppy coding"; failing to parse that CSS is a browser failure, not your failure.

Comment: Which browsers have the same user agent string?

Answer (score 5):

Two reasons:

1. It is **impossible** to detect the browser in use on the client end of things. You can sniff the `user-agent` header sent with the request (if one is present), but it is only as dependable as the browser makers — and the users (since users can disable or alter the header value) — allow it to be.
2. Using browser-specific CSS, DOM or Javascript "features" encourages non-standard implementations. See http://www.webstandards.org/ for why this is important. What you're suggesting would be a return to the "dark ages" of web development.

It is far better to simply fail or display a banner on your page noting that the browser the client is using is non-standard and, given how cheap browser are — free! — suggesting that the user would have a better experience on the web if they get a better browser.

Jon Postel (may he rest in peace) once said that for robustness applications should be strict about what they emit and tolerant about what they accept. Early HTTP implementations and early HTML rendering engines were tolerant in the extreme about what they would accept and that ultimately lead to the Great Browser Wars, with web browsers implementing all manner of non-standard extensions and web servers serving up all sorts of broken, malformed markup. I would argue that we would have been far better off if browser makers would have simply thrown errors on receiving non-standard or malformed data.

In response to the OPs question:

> I'm trying to understand why these errors/warnings are ignored by most sites?

The short answer is because the Standard mandates that particular behaviour. See §4.2 of the CSS Standard at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#parsing-errors.

Comment: In a wonderful world, you were right. But there's many thing you could not to unless write browser specific rules. Concerning the browser detection with the user-agent, all major browsers which represents 99.99% of the browser used, tell who they are, so it's for me a reliable information.

Comment: @pure_code This is an answer to your question, why should it be removed? Upvoting instead.

Comment: @Gael That's not the point. People can spoof the user agent, therefore faking what browser they're actually using. My philosophy is "well, that's their fault", but if you rely on the user agent to render/style certain things, it's not guaranteed to be correct

Comment: people who spoof the user agent do not deserve to have a beautiful rendering:)

Comment: @Gael Exactly, I agree :) Haha unfortunately, most people won't. I'm sure there's reasons why people do it, blah blah blah

Comment: @Gael and pure_code - I have spoofed the user-agent string because of idiotic sites that "work best in IE6" and wouldn't even show me their content. The site worked perfectly after spoofing, so there was no reason to deny entry in the first place. With modern browsers there is absolutely no cause to write browser-specific anything (except occasional hacks to work around browser bugs *cough*ie*cough*) if you use something like jQuery and write good CSS. I have never had to do any browser sniffing to make a webapp work. Use feature detection if necessary, but never sniff the user-agent.

Comment: I agree that it's not a good thing to make browser specific code. But it can happen (for example if you want to use FileSystem, ...), and the user-agent is generaly a good information (regarding to the percentage of people who are able to change it). And if the user give a wrong information, it's not my problem. There's also tools like modernizr which is more efficient.

Comment: @Gael: Firewalls and proxies often strip or munge the `user-agent` header as well, due to security concerns. Knowing the browser and its specific version is useful information to Bad Guys looking to exploit a weakness.

Comment: ok for proxies, but here we are on client side, so there's, normaly, nothing to steal.

Comment: I de-selected the answer b.c. it is not impossible to determine the browser for normal users, i.e. not spoofing.  If you can provide one case in which two different browsers return the same user agent string I will mark as an answer.